# I need a circuit for a linear integrator using a capacitance multiplier

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitance, linear, integrator

There are various circuit topologies for capacitance multipliers using op-amps.  I need to implement a linear integrator where it would be advantageous to reduce the size of the integrating capacitor by (say) a factor of ten.

Are there any topologies for this?

Comment: Why do you need this? there are many pros and cons depending on current and leakage

Comment: @Tony, the integrator is on a PCB where size and cost are limited.  I want to assess whether we should just use a larger cap, or whether we can use a much smaller one with a multiplier and not sacrifice other aspects of the performance.  The application is a low noise environment.

Comment: You did not answer my question on current leakage current. What T=RC?  Any Op Amp integrates according to RC

Comment: @Tony.  the integrator currently uses R= 20k, C=330nF.  The amplitude of the integrator waveform is around 100 mV.  The op-amp is nothing remarkable - TLV6001 - but has good bias current specs (1pA) GBW=1MHz, noise 28nV/rHz.  The design benefits by increasing the capacitor to 3 uF, we are trying to assess whether using a capacitance multiplier will give the same performance benefit.

Comment: What is your acceptance criteria for 0V offset error and max R that you can use if input R’s are balanced.   Are trying to compare with this? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cap-mult-op.svg. then use a plastic cap for low leakage.

Comment: The existing topology uses a "conventional" integrator where the integrating cap. is connected between the output and inverting input.  The ciruit you referenced requires one end of the cap. to be connected to ground.  We would need to look at whether we can change to an integrator topology that has a grounded cap.  The existing integrator meets our requirements, but needs a 3u3 cap, which is unavailable in Lo-K ceramic.

Comment: @rossmcm for increasing the time constant you also could use a T-network with 3 resistors instead of a single resistor at the input of the opamp. A factor of 10 is no problem.

Comment: @rossmcm A simple method for multiplying the feedback capacitor is to use an additional fixed gain amplifier in the feedback loop. Using this method you can create inverting or non-inv. integrator stages - depending on the feedback connection (inv. or non-inv. input node of the main opamp).

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqmm1F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Two integrator circuits (inverting, non-inverting) with enlarged time constants using an additional gain block in the feedback path.